# Excel experts - need your advice in converting text to date without formula in a template

Tags: excel, date, text, format

I need to format a column which is a text. Example '2018-06-21T22:37:06.19' I need to convert it to date only. I am aware of applying formula but that needs an additional column. But I need to format in the existing column as I am creating a template for a report and the template applies the format to everything. But the format is just not working !!

Comment: You can't do this conversion simply with a format. You need to either use a helper column, or use VBA.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is not possible with just formatting, without an extra column or a macro or automation of excel.

Comment: Great job for downvoting a typo !! Very motivating for a new person in stack overflow. I got demoted from 16 to 14. Amazing !!!

Comment: @PhiMasterG and Olly I started to believe that when I ran out of options. But I have heard there are experts in this group. So needed to reach out. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

*Formula* solution:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("T",A1)-1))
```

*VBA* Solution:

```
Sub ConvertToDates(ByRef rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rng
        c.Value = DateValue(Split(c.Value, "T")(0))
        c.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Next c
End Sub

Sub ConvertSelectionToDates()
    ConvertToDates Selection
End Sub
```